# How much should I pursue the headhunter?

Tags: professionalism, hiring-process

**TL;DR:** I am stuck in hiring process because of wrong validation of one of the automatic steps of hiring process for new tester. As already experienced tester I know that fixing bugs costs time. But recent communication with headhunter let me in belief that such issue should be fast fix. How much should I push the issue to know if its fixed?

---

I got recently contacted by a headhunter about new job. While I am totally happy at my current position, the job offer was so interesting, that I decided to apply for the job and see how do I stack up.

However, the new company hiring process is 100% online and one of the steps requires to fill in my personal data, namely Skype account for later interview (should I pass tests which are automatic)

As a tester by profession, I discovered bug on the page: My skype account is connected through my Microsoft account and therefore my Skype ID is my e-mail adress. However, the web form for inserting skype account has a validation which refuses `@` sign to be entered into the field intended for skype.

So, I told as a form of joke, that I definitly fulfill requirements for a good tester, because I am finding bugs even before being hired. I got back answer that I should describe this to the support of that website.

I did describe the issue and got back answer, that this id going to be escalated to the DEV team of the site and I will be contacted back.

Next working day I have been contacted by headhunter about what is the resolution, where I basically copypasted answer from the support.

The day after, I got again contacted by this headhunter, asking me about if I got any resolution of this issue. (No). So I got asked to let the headhunter know if I receive any answer from the support until end of the day (Did not get any solution and told headhunter so).

The last e-mail from headhunter literally reads:

> I apologize for that Pavel, I will investigate the situation and get back to you.

Now. As a tester I know that fixing bugs can take some time and sometimes much more than just several working days (especially if it is generally minor issue like validation affecting just one user).

But, previous conversation made me feel like that issue should be fixed soon and I will be able to continue the hiring process.

While nothing is critical on my side about if I will be hired or not, it makes me now bit nervous in how should I proceed next.

On one hand I do not want to look desperate in needing new job by pushing the headhunter about how to proceed next. On another hand I would like to know if a job posting several levels better (and thus several levels more demanding) is something I could fit for or not.

During describing this issue, I offered the headhunter that I could create new Skype account to meet the form validations. But obviously, I would like to keep this option as very last one.

How should I proceed next?

Comment: Forget it.  He's not a very good headhunter if he asks you to apply online.  Every job application I've had through a recruiter gets my resume directly onto the Hiring Manager (plus the recruiter selling me to them).   What's the point of a headhunter if they make you go through an automated selection process?  Go find the hiring manager and talk directly to him/her.

Comment: The headhunter is from the same company actually. And honestly, having first hiring steps being fully automated for technical jobs sounds like good idea

Comment: Then why do they have a headhunter?  It's like hiring a bank clerk to sit beside an ATM.  It's redundant and stupid.  Is the online system so bad that they need the headhunter?  Then get rid of the system!  Is the online system sufficient?  Make the headhunter do something that online system's can't!  Like directly handing good candidates to the hiring manager.  If you're a bad fit, tell you to go away!  Don't tell you to "apply online".  He doesn't know if you're a good fit?  He's useless!  Don't have a headhunter.  See?  It just makes no sense to have a headhunter tell you to apply online.

Comment: @PavelJanicek Regardless you agree with an automated process or not (my company doesn't. I work for a tech company, we have amazing inhouse recruiters -- if someone didn't finish a degree for a good reason, a script is not going to understand that, for example), you have to agree the way they're resolving this mess show it's a not very organized company and should have your reconsideration as to whether you want to work there or not.

Comment: **ADDENDUM** I got contacted by the support to enter dummy data and that such data will be replaced directly in the database. At least now I know how to proceed should I be hired: I will talk with my current manager about how to get to the same position at my current job

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a simple change on validation, they have bad support if this is not resolved almost immediately. It would take less time to fix then writing the email making an excuse. Just speaking from my own experience with my own sites though. I have seen some shockingly slow support from others, normally I try and find a way to take their client.

In terms of pursuing the headhunter, I would invest a few minutes and create the new account and move forwards. Then I would inform the headhunter I had done this. You have already made an impression as a troubleshooter, now make an impression as someone who resolves problems quickly and competently without fuss.

Comment: The last sentence nailed it!!

Answer (score 2):

These sort of changes and deployments typically move at a glacial pace. I wouldn't hold my breath if I were you.

You might consider creating a separate account simply for this application.

Answer (score 0):

Never chase a headhunter. Let him chase you. Be confident and stop all communication. If he needs you , he will come back.

Comment: This advice's validity depends on how desperate you are and how desirable the position is.